# What's the advantage of the M249 over the Negev?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Seems like there's no real reason to get the M249. The Negev, only slightly more expensive than the M249, gets a crazy fire-rate, crazy accuracy from the first burst, and much more ammo per magazine.

Is there any reason to pick the M249 over the Negev then? I find it very hard to pick the M249 over the Negev, only when I'm running extremely low on money, and even then, it feels much worse than reliable ones like the AWP or the AK/M4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the wiki pages of [*Negev*](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Negev) and [*M249*](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/M249), the advantages of *M249* over *Negev* are:

- Slightly higher armor penetration(80 vs. 75)
- Better accurate range(22m vs. 18m)

But there are some disadvantages as well:

- Slower rate of fire(750rpm vs. 1000rpm)
- Lower damage(32 vs. 35)
- Less ammo(100 vs. 150)

And they are par on the following specs:

- Reload speed(5.7 sec)
- Running speed(195 ups)
- Kill reward(150%)

From my personal experience the only advantage of *M249* over *Negev* is accuracy on long(er) ranges and much less recoil(however, none of them has decent recoil, both shoot pretty much anywhere except for where you aim when you shoot full auto).

Comment: I actually think of slower rate of fire as a + point when it comes to using it at longer ranges. that combined with the slightly better recoil means this gun is much more accurate and in the end you can really improve damage done by getting more shots on target

Comment: @Flaunting true, but you can also shoot bursts or semi(and I'm pretty sure you will not shoot full auto unless you are in a very close combat). And as OP mentioned, there are also *AK*/*M4*/*AWP* which perform a lot better on mid-long range than *M249*/*Negev*

Comment: I was only mentioning it was a bonus as the OPs question was aimed at, is there any reason to pick the m249 and i think it is an added reason

Comment: I want to know the advantages gameplay wise.  Stats mean nothing, and only exist on paper. I want to know how my regular gameplay can be affected with the m249 or the negev